# change root context of Vaadin 7 application

Tags: java, vaadin7

I have my vaading application running on /*
Here the configuration:

```
@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = ApplicationUI.class, widgetset = "com.myproject.bo.AppWidgetSet")
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }
```

I want to move vaadin app to /vaadin/* but if I change the config to be

```
@WebServlet(value = "/vaadin/*", asyncSupported = true)
```

I got error Failed to load the bootstrap javascript: ./../VAADIN/vaadinBootstrap.js

How can I actually move Vaadin app?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following web Servlet config

```
@WebServlet(value = {"/vaadin/*","/VAADIN/*"}, asyncSupported = true)
```

And restart your sever. This should work fine.

Thanks.